# Reading image links with screen readers

Tags: html, image, hyperlink, wai-aria, alt

I am creating a dummy porfolio page for FreeCodeCamp's project and I want to make it as accessible as possible. So here is the problem -

```
<a href="../1_tribute_page/" target="_blank" class="project_link" aria-label="Link To Neil Armstrong Tribute Page">
    <figure>
        <div class="preview_wrapper">
            <img src="previews/tribute_page.jpg" alt="Link To Neil Armstrong Tribute Page"<!--This alt text is read-->>
        </div>
        <figcaption><span>Tribute Page</span></figcaption>
    </figure>
</a>
```

In this code the alt text of the image is read by the screen reader, which is good and what I want, but then it later starts reading the complete link like 'h' 't' 't' 'p' 's' 'colon' 'slash' 'slash' and so on.

How can I make it stop reading the whole link and only the alt or aria label.

Also can I remove the aria label if it is not being used.

I am using the [nvda screen reader](https://www.nvaccess.org/download/) to test this as don't know about any other screen reader.

Thank you very much for the help. :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with screenreaders but I'd try debugging this by doing the following: 1. changing the order of attributes in your `img` tag (write `alt` first and then `src`) 2. mess around with string inside `alt` and see what happens (eg. add greater than characters (`>`) in the string) 3. add closing image tag (`</img>`) and see what happens. 4. verify your html code is formatted properly (either by running it on your browser or submitting it through some html checker tool)

Comment: I did all those things but nothing changed apparently it might be a bug in NVDA or firefox that makes this happen as it works correctly in chromium based browsers. But thank you very much for the suggestion :).